postgresql connection syntax error at or near ":"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.DatabaseConnectors;
using DMSSWE.LOGWRITER;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Common;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Interfaces;
using DMSSWE.SECURITY.WEBAPI.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

//above are the libreries

public int RoleTempInsertWithRoleID(string[] connectionValues, ROLEDTO oROLEDTO)
{
    int roleId = 0;
    int maxRoleId = 0;
    int maxTempRoleId = 0;
    int result = 0;

    try
    {
        using (DBConnector oCloudConnection = new DBConnector(connectionValues[0], Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1])))
        {
            StringBuilder varname1 = new StringBuilder();
            varname1.Append("SELECT MAX(ROLE_ID) AS MAX_ROLE_ID \n");
            varname1.Append("FROM SROLE \n");
            varname1.Append("WHERE 1=1 \n");
            varname1.Append("AND COMPANY_ID=?COMPANY_ID \n");
            varname1.Append("AND PRODUCT_ID=?PRODUCT_ID;");

            oCloudConnection.CommandText = varname1.ToString();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Clear();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "COMPANY_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.COMPANY_ID });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "PRODUCT_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.PRODUCT_ID });
            using (IDataReader dr = oCloudConnection.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    maxRoleId = DataReaderHelper.GetValue<int>(dr, "MAX_ROLE_ID");
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        using (DBConnector oCloudConnection = new DBConnector(connectionValues[0], Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1])))
        {
            StringBuilder varname1 = new StringBuilder();
            varname1.Append("SELECT MAX(ROLE_ID) AS MAX_ROLE_ID \n");
            varname1.Append("FROM SROLETEMP \n");
            varname1.Append("WHERE 1=1 \n");
            varname1.Append("AND COMPANY_ID=?COMPANY_ID \n");
            varname1.Append("AND PRODUCT_ID=?PRODUCT_ID;");

            oCloudConnection.CommandText = varname1.ToString();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Clear();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "COMPANY_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.COMPANY_ID });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "PRODUCT_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.PRODUCT_ID });
            using (IDataReader dr = oCloudConnection.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    maxTempRoleId = DataReaderHelper.GetValue<int>(dr, "MAX_ROLE_ID");
                }
                dr.Close();
            }
        }
        if (maxRoleId == 0 && maxTempRoleId == 0)
        {
            oROLEDTO.ROLE_ID = "1";
        }
        else if (maxRoleId > maxTempRoleId)
        {
            result = maxRoleId + 1;
            oROLEDTO.ROLE_ID = result.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            result = maxTempRoleId + 1;
            oROLEDTO.ROLE_ID = result.ToString();
        }
        using (DBConnector oCloudConnection = new DBConnector(connectionValues[0], Convert.ToInt32(connectionValues[1])))
        {
            StringBuilder varname1 = new StringBuilder();
            varname1.Append("INSERT INTO SROLETEMP \n");
            varname1.Append("( \n");
            varname1.Append("COMPANY_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("PRODUCT_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("ROLE_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("ROLE_NAME, \n");
            varname1.Append("ROLE_DESCRIPTION, \n");
            varname1.Append("ROLE_TYPE, \n");
            varname1.Append("EVENT_ACTION, \n");
            varname1.Append("EVENT_STATUS, \n");
            varname1.Append("CREATED_DATETIME, \n");
            varname1.Append("CREATED_USER, \n");
            varname1.Append("CREATED_USER_CC, \n");
            varname1.Append("CREATED_MACHINE, \n");
            varname1.Append("CREATED_MACHINE_IP, \n");
            varname1.Append("MODIFIED_DATETIME, \n");
            varname1.Append("MODIFIED_USER, \n");
            varname1.Append("MODIFIED_USER_CC, \n");
            varname1.Append("MODIFIED_MACHINE, \n");
            varname1.Append("MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP \n");
            varname1.Append(") \n");
            varname1.Append("VALUES \n");
            varname1.Append("( \n");
            varname1.Append("?COMPANY_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("?PRODUCT_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("?ROLE_ID, \n");
            varname1.Append("?ROLE_NAME, \n");
            varname1.Append("?ROLE_DESCRIPTION, \n");
            varname1.Append("?ROLE_TYPE, \n");
            varname1.Append("?EVENT_ACTION, \n");
            varname1.Append("?EVENT_STATUS, \n");
            varname1.Append("?CREATED_DATETIME, \n");
            varname1.Append("?CREATED_USER, \n");
            varname1.Append("?CREATED_USER_CC, \n");
            varname1.Append("?CREATED_MACHINE, \n");
            varname1.Append("?CREATED_MACHINE_IP, \n");
            varname1.Append("?MODIFIED_DATETIME, \n");
            varname1.Append("?MODIFIED_USER, \n");
            varname1.Append("?MODIFIED_USER_CC, \n");
            varname1.Append("?MODIFIED_MACHINE, \n");
            varname1.Append("?MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP \n");
            varname1.Append(");");

            oCloudConnection.CommandText = varname1.ToString();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Clear();
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "COMPANY_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.COMPANY_ID });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "PRODUCT_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.PRODUCT_ID });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "ROLE_ID", Value = oROLEDTO.ROLE_ID });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "ROLE_NAME", Value = oROLEDTO.ROLE_NAME });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "ROLE_DESCRIPTION ", Value = oROLEDTO.ROLE_DESCRIPTION.Trim() });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "ROLE_TYPE", Value = oROLEDTO.ROLE_TYPE });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "EVENT_ACTION", Value = oROLEDTO.EVENT_ACTION });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "EVENT_STATUS", Value = oROLEDTO.EVENT_STATUS });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "CREATED_DATETIME", Value = oROLEDTO.CREATED_DATETIME });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "CREATED_USER", Value = oROLEDTO.CREATED_USER });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "CREATED_USER_CC", Value = oROLEDTO.CREATED_USER_CC });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "CREATED_MACHINE", Value = oROLEDTO.CREATED_MACHINE });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "CREATED_MACHINE_IP", Value = oROLEDTO.CREATED_MACHINE_IP });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "MODIFIED_DATETIME", Value = oROLEDTO.MODIFIED_DATETIME });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "MODIFIED_USER", Value = oROLEDTO.MODIFIED_USER });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "MODIFIED_USER_CC", Value = oROLEDTO.MODIFIED_USER_CC });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "MODIFIED_MACHINE", Value = oROLEDTO.MODIFIED_MACHINE });
            oCloudConnection.Parameters.Add(new Parameter { Name = "MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP", Value = oROLEDTO.MODIFIED_MACHINE_IP });
            if (oCloudConnection.ExecuteQuery() > 0)
            {
                roleId = Convert.ToInt32(oROLEDTO.ROLE_ID);
            }
            return roleId;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        DMSLogger.Write(ex);
        throw;
    }
}

this code throws an error System.Exception: '42601: syntax error at or near ":" and I tried several times but couldn't solve this error throws from if (oCloudConnection.ExecuteQuery() > 0)
Also the ExecuteReader() methord convrets ? to : because this uses a PostgreSQL database
I want to correct this error. I tried removing ? marks but it gave another error System.Exception: '42703: column "company_id" does not exist but in my database column company_id is present. Also I try running this using similar MSSql database (ExecuteReader() change ? to @) and it work fine. to this i use c#.

Parameters are marked using @ not ?. You don't need StringBuilder, just use a verbatim string @"SELECT..." and then you can embed newlines. If you are only getting one value, then don't use a reader, instead use ExecuteScalar Don't roll your own SERIAL type, the database can autoincrement it for you.
